# Correct question sentence construction

Tags: word-order, questions

Which one is correct to say ?

I have read both the sentence consructions and both seems correct to me . Is there any grammar rule ?

a) Where is the location?

b) Where the location is ?

Comment: Please be aware that there should be no space between the last word in a sentence and the ending punctuation.  It may seem like a small thing, but native speakers notice these kind of basic mistakes, and judge your English ability accordingly.

Comment: Note that most fluent English speakers won't use the word **location** in a **where?** question because the question **where?** implicitly asks for a location. They're more likely to ask, "Where is it?"

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is:

> Where is the location?

Questions are usually formed with [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion) in English.

Sometimes non-interrogative sentences are simply spoken with a questioning inflection (or written with a question mark) to imply a question. This case would be written

> The location is where?

(but never "Where the location is?" by itself)

Comment: As a footnote, "Where the location is" might be found as a part of a longer statement, such as, "This will be a film where the location is as important as the cast." But as you stay, it doesn't work as a standalone sentence or question.

Comment: Or more likely to cause confusion: "I wonder where the location is".

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the location

This makes sense but is unnatural imo. The inversion ( the location is where?) as pointed out in the other answer also sounds unnatural to me.

If you want to change the sentence up a bit, I would probably say

> Where is the place located at?
>
> Where is the place at?

These sound natural to me